# I've got a JSON file that I'm trying to extract values from with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to pull each of the viewer names from a JSON file in PHP.

I've looked around the Internet extensively for a working example that will offer me the result I desire without much success.

I'm really struggling to find an example that fits my needs on the Internet to help me with what is likely a very simple thing to accomplish.

I've got a JSON file that spits out several values on the Internet and I'm looking to extract every single line from one particular section.

Seeing a working example will likely help me understand what I am doing.

The JSON file that I am using for example is: 
https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/dansgaming/chatters

I am trying to extract each single line from the "viewers" section in this file.

I've captured the data using the following PHP:

```
$testviewers = json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/' . $streamName . '/chatters'), true);
var_dump($testviewers['chatters']['viewers']);
```

It turns out this isn't having the desired result for me.

I simply want each line in the viewer's section to be echoed out with page breaks.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried about two hundred different approaches to this one and have to admit this is my first real time working with JSON.

I've tried to search the Internet for answers and found many tutorials but none have made any sense to me and I know that seeing how to accomplish the result will help me learn exactly what should be going on.

In an ideal world, it will simply output each "viewer" on a separate line that I can work with. If I could echo each of them and then concatenate with a page break or the word "viewer:" before each one this would be a huge help and I'll be able to take it further and likely learn a great deal in the process.

Comment: can you please paste json here....?

Comment: so what's the issue? why doesn't your code work?

Comment: @GyandeepSharma The JSON is very, very, very, large. This link is the actual JSON. The JSON file has over 10 thousand lines. You can find it here: https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/dansgaming/chatters

Comment: are you asking how to do `echo implode("<br>", $testviewers['chatters']['viewers'])`?

Comment: @Gordon I tried that and keep getting a blank page. Perhaps this is another issue. I don't get any errors, just a blank space where that should be working.

Comment: check max_execution_time

Comment: Yes, it's another issue. make sure you have error reporting enabled and/or check your error log.

Comment: Thank you @AZinkey and Gordon this was exactly it. I feel so stupid right now. I searched and searched and realized I had commented out my error reporting.

Comment: you probably want to delete the question then since it will attract useless answers. point in case: see answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this my way echo from json

```
$json = json_decode($response, true);
foreach($json['chatters'] as $key => $value)
{
  if(!empty($value['viewers']))
  {
   $VIEWER = $value['viewers'];
   $VIEWER = addslashes($VIEWER );
   $VIEWER = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $VIEWER ));
  }
  else
  {
    $VIEWER = '';
  }
   echo 'VIEWER = '.$VIEWER .'</br>';
}
```

just make sure the foreach is true, maybe can help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue here was a PHP error that wasn't displaying. The code was timing out because of how large the JSON file was and a low limit on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want....

```
$array = json_decode($your_json,true); 
foreach($array['chatters']['viewers'] as $r) echo $r.'<br>';
```